# How is a transition between drywall and wood typically handled?

Tags: trim, finishing, drywall

[image]I just finished sheet rocking my living room and am stuck at a stand-still.  My ceiling is 12' feet high at the tallest point and slopes down to 8'.  That said, at the 12' wall, the sheetrock only goes up 8' and is then met by a lap and gap type wood, which then continues up to the ceiling. The wood then slopes (on the wall). At the 8' point of the ceiling, the sheetrock butts up to the ceiling.

My question is...How would I install a crown moulding or transition piece at the point where the sheetrock meets the wood?  The previous owners had a painted 1x4 where the paneling (now sheetrock) met the wood. However, I am wanting something a bit nicer than just a 1x4 transition.

Either I am the only person out there with a room like this or I am searching incorrectly on Google.  Does anyone have any ideas or pictures on this? I can definitely provide pictures if needed. I am tempted to pull the wood all the way to ceiling and continue the sheetrock all the way up. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Need a picture of the area

Comment: If you like the wood then it would be a shame to rip it down. On the other hand if you secretly hate the wood then it is an easy decision to go all the way up with the sheetrock.

Comment: Well, I don't mind the wood but (as with most decisions) my wife has the final say...  She likes the wood and it's a fight that I'm not sure I'll win.  That said, I'm pretty sure I'm stuck trying to find a way to install crown moulding here or other transition.

Comment: You definitely don't want crown moulding...this is the wrong application for that. I'd go simple over ornate and also stick with a 1x4-ish strip of wood. Or maybe even just leave it as-is. Could we get a close up photo of the transition?

Comment: Are both faces flush with each other, or does the wood stick out a bit further than the drywall?

Comment: The faces are flush. The gaps are ~1/4" - 1" where the drywall and wood meet. The idea to route the wood prior to putting the Sheetrock up is genius and certainly something that I never thought about. Unfortunately, the Sheetrock is already in place. That said, I think a transition strip would work perfect here...never thought about that either. I will still post more of the gaps and other areas of the room. The ideas and advice are appreciated more than you know!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a few options I can think of.

## Lap joint

If the wood is a bit thicker than the drywall, you could use a router to remove some of the material on the back side of the lowest plank (may require installing an additional plank, or extending the drywall). Then allow the lowest plank to lap over the drywall. Make sure you leave enough of a gap between the two materials, to allow for expansion and contraction.

[image: Lap joint]

## Transition

Another option would be to use a transition strip, like the ones commonly used in flooring. You'd use T-molding if the materials are even with each other, or a reducer if they're not.

[image: T-molding]

## Molding

A simple 1x4 like the previous owners had, or a more decorative piece of molding could be used.

[image: Decorative molding]